# Get Twitter user's name in Android

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I have been running around in circles trying to solve this.
I use Fabric to connect to Twitter from my Android app.
I have no problem getting the username but for the life of me I can't get the user's real name.

I have looked at many posts here and nothing helps.
I looked at this: [Twitter fabric, get user's name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766084/twitter-fabric-get-users-name)
which seemed to be the same but all the classes or methods specified there don't exist (ConfigurationBuilder, TwitterFactory, twitter.showUser).

Comment: if you look here https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets  you see that in the json has a "name" parameter. I guess you're looking for it isn't it ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that link. I am not looking to access the tweets. All I want is the users real name (the same way I can get his username and userid).